# how can we get the productName or productId of the error image if image is onerror

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

hi  I am new to angularjs, I am trying to get the name of the `product` or `product` id if that particular product image is failed to load in `<img>` tag so that i can do some stuff by using that `product Id`, but how can I get that particular product Id or name when image failed to load,

i am using directives here and i am trying to get that productId in directive link function

### controller

```
angular.module('myApp').controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
scope.products=[
               { productName:"Mobile",
                 productImage:"someImage.jpg",
                 productId: 1              
               },
                { productName:"wallet",
                 productImage:"someImage22.jpg",
                 productId: 2              
               },
                { productName:"headphones",
                 productImage:"image3.jpg",
                 productId: 3              
               }
              ]
});

index.html
---------
<div ng-repeat="products in products">
    <my-directive data="products"><my-directive>
</div>
```

### here is my directive

```
.directive('myDirective',function($state){
return{
  restrict:'E',
  scope:{
    data:'='
  },
  templateUrl:'template.html',
  link: function(scope,elem,attr){
    var image = document.getElementById('imageId');
     image.onerror=function(){
       console.log("image loading error") // here console is also not printing.
       console.log("product ID") // here i want error loding image productId.
      }
  }
}
});
```

### here is my template.html

```
<div>
<h2>{{data.productName}}</h2>

<a href="example.com"><img id="imageId" src="{{data.productImage}}"> </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `scope.data.productId`?

Comment: you must have a scope variable `products` in the parent scope of `<my-directive>`

Comment: i updated my code with controller @CharanCherry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**my-directive.js**

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive("myDirective", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      templateUrl: 'my-directive.html',
      scope: {
        data: '='
      }
    };
  })
  .directive('checkImg', function() {
   return {
     restrict: 'EA',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
         element.bind('error', function($event) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(attrs.name)); // Here is your product
         });
       }
   }
});
```

**my-directive.html**

```
<div>

  <h2>{{data.productName}}</h2>
  <img ng-src="{{data.productImage}}" name="{{data}}" check-img>
</div>
```

It is not possible with onerror to pass angular data that is `data(product)` in your case. onerror is calling a function that is at outside angular. So, we get that error. We can pass only the event in `onerror="fun(event)"`, Other than that we can't pass anything. In the above code the attribute name is only to hold product data. You can store that product data in another attribute also.

Comment: i tried your code but for me it is giving an error like this `Uncaught ReferenceError: getElem is not defined
    at HTMLImageElement.onerror ((index):1)
onerror @ (index):1
` @CharanCherry

Comment: Instead of `var getElem` use `scope.getElem`

Comment: i updated as like your code also iam getting the same error @CharanCherry

Comment: last and final, use `function getElem` and remove `scope.getElem`

Comment: wait a minute, iam preparing a plunker @CharanCherry

Comment: here is my plunker please check it [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/GVcIBBI5aoYIMCEAf3PZ?p=preview) @CharanCherry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131694/discussion-between-charan-cherry-and-midhunsai).

Comment: how can push all the products of errored images into an array @CharanCherry

Answer (score 0):

Hi i use this directives for images on error:

```
angular
    .module("myappName")
    .directive('errSrc', function () {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('error', function() {
                console.log(attrs);
               // here you can catch the error of image
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and use it :

```
<img data-ng-src={{mysrc}} err-src />
```